# How to find and replace a specific word from a URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to replace the following from my URL on my local machine,

```
localhost/site/pages/pages/about-us
```

So I want it to redirect to `localhost/pages/about-us`

So basically if I click on another page, it should remove "pages/pages" from the URL and replace it with "pages/" only for every page I intend to visit.

HERE IS MY HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^pages/pages/(.*)$ /pages/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your htaccess file in your question in text format, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have just shared the htaccess file.

Comment: Sure, thanks for sharing. Could you please confirm if you want to hit `localhost/pages/about-us` in browser which should be served by `localhost/site/pages/pages/about-us` file in backend? Is it a real file/directory in backend? Kindly confirm these 2 questions, thank you.

Comment: When I click on an href that has localhost/site/pages/about-us whilst inside the same folder pages, and when I click to visit a page in the same pages folder, it then redirects to localhost/site/pages/pages/about-us yet I only want it to remain in localhost/site/pages/about-us for removing the word pages from the header will affect files outside of it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^/pages/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule pages/pages/(.*)$ /pages/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've commented out especially this line that causes error:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
```